# iPad USB flash drive file transfer

Tags: usb, iphone

Can I use a 30 pin to USB adapter to connect a USB flash drive to an iPad and transfer arbitrary files back and forth?

please address specifically:

1. Can ANY file be transferred? Not just Image or Music files?
2. This can be done WITHOUT any modification (jail-breaking)

Please provide references to adapter device specifications and references from reliable sources addressing the above specific points.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this without jailbreaking.

http://www.pocketables.com/2013/02/accessory-review-apple-lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter-for-ipad.html

No, you cannot transfer any arbitrary files.  you cannot transfer documents, txt, source, etc; you can only transfer images and videos.

Comment: Can you rename the arbitrary files to have an image file extension? I know this works to fool Gmail into sending executable files. Perhaps it works here too.

Comment: <www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5f1VmjjczQ> video shows how use an alternate extension to transfer arbitrary files from USB to iPad.  but you cannot transfer files from the iPad to the USB drive using this method.

Comment: Well, it's good to have solid reasons for not owning any Apple products. If you can call that ownership...

Comment: @Passerby these articles and the separation of the SD and USB components doesn't seem to offer any additional capabilites.  see the question, please.